# Excel 2016: A nested if statement error is coming up with the correct # of parenthesis

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

```
IF(C5="","",IF(D5="",C5,IF(E5="",(SUM(C5:D5/2),IF(F5="",(SUM(C5:F5/3),IF(G5="",(SUM(C5:F5/4),IF(H5="",(SUM(C5:G5/5),IF(I5="",(SUM(C5:H5/6),IF(J5="",(SUM(C5:I5/7),IF(K5="",(SUM(C5:J5/8),IF(L5="",(SUM(C5:K5/9),(SUM(C5:L5/10))))))))))))))))))))
```

1.Trying to find an average based on number of trials(columns)

Comment: `SUM(C5:L5/10)` seems wrong and `(SUM(C5:L5/10)` is just plain wrong. You probably want something closer to `SUM(C5:L5)/10` or `AVERAGE(C5:L5)` as demonstrated below. Depending on interim blank cells, the two formulas will produce different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the AVERAGE() worksheet function.

```
=AVERAGE(C5:L5)
```

will give you an average of that range and automatically ignore blanks.

(Edited to reflect that the 7-level nesting limit has been expanded, but this solution is probably still the preferable way to go).

Comment: The limit was raised to 64 nested levels (I think xl2007). From [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-%E2%80%93-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8) *'While Excel will allow you to nest up to 64 different IF functions, it’s not at all advisable to do so.'*

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks for bringing me to the right decade, but yeah, i'd still go with the Average function here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like following purely on the basis of the right number of parentheses? I have removed the ones around each SUM.

```
=IF(C5="","",IF(D5="",C5,IF(E5="",SUM(C5:D5/2),IF(F5="",SUM(C5:F5/3),IF(G5="",SUM(C5:F5/4),IF(H5="",SUM(C5:G5/5),IF(I5="",SUM(C5:H5/6),IF(J5="",SUM(C5:I5/7),IF(K5="",SUM(C5:J5/8),IF(L5="",SUM(C5:K5/9),SUM(C5:L5/10)))))))))))
```